# Is there a decent REST API testing tool that doesn't lack basic features, or gate them behind a paywall?

Tags: rest

Postman is a great tool but it hides vital features (like workspaces with more than 25 requests) behind a paywall. Other so-called alternatives (like Insomnia) either do the same thing, or lack other vital features.

Postman also suffers from the same problem as most Electron apps, in that its UI is designed by people who think they are cleverer than they actually are, with the result that not only is the UX terrible, it also goes completely against the UX standards of the platform it's running on.

Requirements:

- Import OpenAPI Specification (OAS, formerly known as Swagger) documents from a URL and automatically create requests for each one
- Ability to have multiple, different logical groupings of requests (like Postman's workspace)
- Import/export workspaces from/to a file or directory (for version control and CLI purposes)
- Execute an entire workspace, or specific requests(s) within it, from the command-line; OR ability to export workspace in Postman format (could then use newman to test the requests)

Comment: Take a look at https://alternativeto.net/software/postman/?license=free If you find a good one, please post ans answer here (and accept it). Doing so will help others in future. Welcome aboard, and good luck :-)

Answer (score 3):

I would recommend [curl](https://curl.haxx.se/). I do all my API testing with `curl`. You can write scripts with `curl` requests.

If you want a GUI, I would recommend [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/). It can also run from the command line. It's more complicated to use and figure out, especially for REST API requests. It will save the test into a XML file.

Neither imports OAS.

Answer (score 3):

I use [SOAPUI](https://www.soapui.org/) to test REST APIs. You can save the full request and get pretty verbose details on both send and receive channels. It supports plain text, JSON, and XML messages (and probably other ones that I don't use).

Comment: This looks very good, thanks. I like that it is sponsored by Smart Bear, as I really like their test tools.